# gsutil zip directory on google cloud storage

Tags: directory, zip, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

is it possible to compress file or directory of google cloud storage without download it first and re-upload?

I think I need some tools similar like http://googlegenomics.readthedocs.org/en/latest/use_cases/compress_or_decompress_many_files/

thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. There is no way to ask GCS to directly compress or decompress objects entirely within GCS. You can certainly copy them elsewhere in the cloud (GCE, for instance) and operate on them there, or you could download an uncompressed object as a compressed object simply by using the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header, but, again, not without taking it out of GCS in some fashion.

Answer (score 8):

From

> https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/your-bucket

open a cloud shell (top right of the page), then:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://your-bucket .
zip your-bucket.zip ./your-bucket
gsutil cp your-bucket.zip gs://your-bucket
```

Strictly it is not happening in place within your storage but within the cloud.

Comment: "zip -r your-bucket.zip ./your-bucket"  -r to zip all the files recursively